# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I have a list of string given below :

```
[u'Any subscription charges to avail this facility',
 u'credited into the beneficiary\u2019s account',
 u'funds have been credited in the beneficiary\u2019s account',
 u'Can I reuse VPA']
```

There are some unicode char in string (\u2019) which represent (') punctuation. Please let me know how to remove this as create error. I have used below code to remove but doesn't works:

```
for x in mylist:
  x.encode('ascii','ignore')
  new_list.append(x)
```

But it returns the same list with unicode character. Please help

Comment: Can you a) replace `\u2019` with a simple `'`? or b) use `utf-8` instead of `ascii` encoding?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Can you tell how to do this ? As in code

Comment: `x.encode()` returns the encoded result, it doesn't modify x: You want: `new_list.append(x.encode('ascii','ignore'))`

Comment: Ah, you beat me

Comment: @TemporalWolf, Thanks!! your method works

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending the encoded value to the new_list.

```
for x in mylist:
   new_list.append(x.encode('ascii','ignore'))


['Any subscription charges to avail this facility', 
'credited into the beneficiarys account', 
'funds have been credited in the beneficiarys account', 
'Can I reuse VPA']
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful, especially given the focus of it being useful for future readers (who may have a similar issue). If you want to answer the question, review [answer] and provide more information.